# How to change color of visited row of the list using css in html

Tags: html, css, list

I have taken the links dynamically which are coming in a list. When i click on the link, in other container its page opens. I want to change the visited link color.Basically the block background color. I am able to change color on click. but i need it will stay as it is until n unless i refresh the page. I used

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

ul li{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
    background-color:#7EA5E4;
}

li a:visited, a:active{
    background-color: #09F;
}
```

Please suggest me where i have to do changes.

Comment: Could you further explain your situation, it's a little confusing to read. Maybe create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

From what you've said though, have you tried: `a:visited`, this display the links differently if a user has already visited that link.

Comment: u can check this jsfiddle.net/65v37/10/

Comment: are you passing any href in your anchor tag ?                       It it is then your page will be refresh and again it will show as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like, changing the colour / font family to suite you

```
.Link  A:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif ;
    color: #fff;
}
```

The `.link` is a custom class

Hope this can help,

Thanks,

Jack.

Comment: this i had done.but i need after removing my mouse also on that link, the color should remain changed.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by that, you could also try A:active & A:hover

Answer (score 0):

That is, what `:visited` does. But you "block" is the list item, which can't be visited, because it isn't a link. Style you anchor as block by moving the appropriate styles from the list item to the anchor. That way you also could style the background.

Comment: ok.. if i want to change just the link color only.den?? If i remove remove the cursor then also color remain unchanged

Comment: @user1597569 I don't understand your problem!?

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are looking like this:- http://tinkerbin.com/VsbhpxGi

you just have to make `.active` class and define in `li`

like this :-

```
li.active {
    background-color:#7EA5E4;
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

i hope you are looking like this if you will click on any link so that link will be active...... see the updated answer...

http://tinkerbin.com/Fm0lRO8Z

Comment: yeah. that is f9. But i need if i click on that link than the color changes.

Comment: i hope you are looking like this if you will click on any link so that link will be active...... see the updated answer....

Comment: yes. but on click red color comes and on removing cursor it disappears. I want that red color remains after click also, if i remove cursor from it then also.

Comment: @user1597569: there are three comments in this question, and its answers, stating that they're having trouble understanding you. While I accept that English might not be your first language, or the first language of those with difficulties understanding you, might I ask that you don't further complicate the issue by using unnecessary text-speak, such as 'f9'? Please try to communicate to the best of your abilities, it will aid you in getting the help you need and the answers you want.